# Disparar un evento del Form1 desde el Form2

Tags: c#

en el Form1 tengo un evento llamado "CargaGestion" que se acciona cuando se carga el Form1, es decir desde el Load, este evento funciona OK. Ahora lo que necesito es disparar este mismo evento pero desde un boton que tengo en el Form2, alguien me podria decir como hacerlo, que codigo tendria que poner en ambos formularios para que me funcione.

Muchas gracias
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] té invito a que hagas el [tour] para que ganes tú primera medallas y de paso visites [ask]. Para que edites tu pregunta y sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

No se acciona ningun evento desde otro formulario, lo que haces es llevar la funcionalidad a un metodo comun que expones para ser accedido desde ambos puntos

Para esto comunicas los forms, aqui

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

explica como puede lograrlo

Lo resuelves con interfaces lo que permite desacoplar la interaccion

Para la primera defines la interfaz como ser

```
interface IForm{
   void MetodoComun();
}
```

entonces en el form padre implementas la interfaz

```
public class CargaGestion: Form, IForm {

    //codigo del form

    public CargaGestion_Load(...){

      MetodoComun(); //el codigo que tenias en el load lo llevas a un metodo

    }

    //implementas el metodo de la interfaz
    public void MetodoComun()
    {
       //codigo comun que tenias en el load
    }

    private void button1_Click(...){
      frmHijo frm = new frmHijo(this);
      frm.Show()
    } 
}
```

Es importante ese `this` en el constructor del form hijo al instanciarlo

Despues el form hijo invocas el metodo definido en el interface

```
public class frmHijo : Form{

     private IForm _form;

     public frmHijo(IForm form){ //este es el constructor
          _form = form;
     }

     private void button1_Click(...)
     {
         _form.MetodoComun();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Leandro, esta respuesta es casi palabra por palabra la misma que pusiste en el duplicado que he marcado. En estos casos se debe enlazar a la duplicada en lugar de volver a responder.

Comment: La tecnica es la misma pero la adapte a la consulta, ya que una solo implica invocar una funcionalidad comun, mientras que la otra quiere pasar datos entre forms. En realidad la respuesta seria solo el link de mi blog donde lo explico como comunicar forms, pero como se que solo un link no les gusta como respuesta lo completo con algo de codigo adaptado a la pregunta

Comment: la tecnica es la misma, la respuesta es diferente porque la otra se podria resolver usando eventos en cambio esta no lo creo, por eso no sugeri ese camino

Comment: Bueno, el código si te fijas es igual cambiando los nombres de los metodos y del form, por eso decía que era igual. En cuanto al enlace, puedes añadirlo como lo has hecho o ponerlo en un comentario sin problemas. Pero en este caso, yo personalmente considero que es un duplicado exacto como así marque.